# HTML table to PDF using IText

Tags: java, itext

```
public class FontItext {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.A4,55f,30f,30f,30f);
        document.setMarginMirroring(true);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D://AAA.pdf"));
        document.open();       
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("D:\\times.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font = new Font(bf);
        Paragraph _p = new Paragraph();       
        ArrayList htmlObjs = (ArrayList)HTMLWorker.parseToList(new StringReader("<table border=1><tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr></table>"),
                null);
        for (int k = 0; k < htmlObjs.size(); ++k) {
            ArrayList<Chunk> chunk = (ArrayList<Chunk>)((Paragraph)htmlObjs.get(k)).getChunks();
            for (int l = 0; l < chunk.size(); l++) {
                Font _original_chunk_font = chunk.get(l).getFont();
                Font _newchunk_font = new Font(bf);
                _newchunk_font.setFamily(_original_chunk_font.getFamilyname());
                _newchunk_font.setStyle(_original_chunk_font.getStyle());
                _newchunk_font.setSize(_original_chunk_font.getSize());
                _newchunk_font.setColor(_original_chunk_font.getColor());
                chunk.get(l).setFont(_newchunk_font);
            }
            _p.add((Element)htmlObjs.get(k));

            document.add((Element)htmlObjs.get(k));

        } 

        document.close();
    }
}
```

**Error...**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph
    at Font.FontItext.main(FontItext.java:46)
```

Hey Guys help me....

Comment: *"Hey Guys help me...."*  Hey guy, ask a question (and no, adding a '?' to the title does *not* make it a question).

Comment: html table to not converted pdf

Comment: That last comment is not a question either.  In fact, it reads like nonsense.  "html table (is) **not converted to** pdf" is a a valid sentence, but is still not a question.  I'll throw you a bone.  Perhaps your question is "How do I solve the ClassCastException?".  If that **is** the question, please edit it into your post so I can delete my comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have so much experience with IText, but the exception says:

replace:

`ArrayList<Chunk> chunk = (ArrayList<Chunk>)((Paragraph)htmlObjs.get(k)).getChunks();`

by

`ArrayList<Chunk> chunk = (ArrayList<Chunk>)((PdfPTable)htmlObjs.get(k)).getChunks();`